# How to iterate through Observable collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, overriding, observablecollection

Hi guys i want to ask that i have a Class with properties like following:

```
public class VLANSPropertyClass
  {
    public string vname { get; set; }

    public int S_No { get; set; }

    public string vid { get; set; }

    public string ip { get; set; }

    public string vports { get; set; }
  }
```

I created an `ObservableCollection` as follows:

```
  public ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass> vlan { get; set; }
  vlan = new ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass>();
```

I am adding all these values in a datagrid:

```
        void AddVlans()
        {
          var serial = new VLANSPropertyClass();
          serial.S_No = vlan.Count + 1;
          Console.WriteLine(serial.S_No);
          serial.vname = VlanName;
          Console.WriteLine(serial.vname);
          serial.vid = VlanID;
          Console.WriteLine(serial.vid);
          serial.ip = VlanIP1 + "." + VlanIP2 + "." + VlanIP3 + "." + VlanIP4;
          Console.WriteLine(serial.ip);
          serial.vports = SelectedVlanPort;
          vlan.Add(serial);
        }
```

The display looks like following image:

[image]

Now i want go through each row and read its values.I tried following but didnt work

```
foreach(VLANSPropertyClass v in vlan)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(v);
     Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Kindly tell me the possible way of reading values from ObservableCollection/Datagrid.Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: i am unable to extract row by row values from datagrid .Each row should be read like a separate object.

Comment: Do you have datagrid bound to the observable collection?

Comment: yes ..datagrid is working fine i just want to get each row value from datagrid and write it on Console !

Comment: Data in rows the same as in collection. So each `v` in your `foreach` is the data of row in datagrid.

Comment: yes but i am unable to see that on Console

Comment: Of course, if you use `Console.WriteLine(v);` you can't see it in the console. You will see the full qualified type name. Override the `ToString` method and build your object string representation.

Comment: You mean `Console.WriteLine(v).ToString()`; ??

Comment: Print actual property like this - `Console.WriteLine(v.vname)`. Similarly for other properties.

Comment: @CodeSnipper - If you are able to resolve the issue. Kindly delete this question if not anticipating anything from the community.

Comment: Thanks to you also @RohitVats ...Your solution also worked ...Why you are saying to delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your class to this...

```
  public class VLANSPropertyClass
    {
        public string vname { get; set; }

        public int S_No { get; set; }

        public string vid { get; set; }

        public string ip { get; set; }

        public string vports { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("Name: {0}, Serial {1}", vname, S_No);
        }
    }
```

This change includes an override to the `ToString` method.  It will be called whenever the framework needs a string representation of your class.

> ToString is the major formatting method in the .NET Framework. It
>   converts an object to its string representation so that it is suitable
>   for display. (For information about formatting support in the .NET
>   Framework, see Formatting Types.)

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx

Using an override to `ToString` will let you do this    `Console.WriteLine(v);`  with expected results.

Answer (score 0):

When you loop through an ObservableCollection<>, accessing it through index returns a complete instance/item of the collection in form of the string, you now need to reference this string using index or property(in case its a user defined type(class)) in order to access the real content, in my case i am doing this to access temp property of an item of the collection mess.

```
mess[mj_key][mn_key][0].Temp.ToString()
```

here i have 3 dimensions, avoid it for now, just understand that 0 index returns string object, i then access temperature using .Temp

Hope it Helps!

Comment: you can at least tell the reason for -1, because i shared what i did. Thanks.